# how to properly persist additional object fields to all records within mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have a node module, in which I'm parsing a .csv file into a collection of mongodb documents.

For each incoming record, I'm adding a few extra metadata fields, which suppose to describe that record.

For some reason, only the first inserted document has those fields, and the rest do not.
What would be the correct way to add these fields, so they are persisted in each inserted document?

Here is my code:

```
exports.excelFileParser = function(fileName, tabName, metadataFields){
    var assert = require('assert');
    console.log(metadataFields);
    if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');

    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var _ = require('underscore');

    var fs = require('fs');

    var Converter=require("csvtojson").core.Converter;

    var  distinctDataFields;

    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/datamanager-03-test';

    var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./uploads/' + fileName);

    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[tabName];

    var metaFields = metadataFields;

    var json_conversion = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

    var csv_conversion = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);

    var csv_lines = csv_conversion.split('\n');

    var dirtyHeaderLine = csv_lines[0];

    var cleanHeaderLine = dirtyHeaderLine.replace(/\./g,"")
        .replace(/ /g,"")
        .replace(/"'"/g,"")
        .replace(/","/g,"")
        .replace(/"\/"/g,"")
        .replace(/"#"/g,"")
        .replace(/\(/g,"")
        .replace(/\)/g,"");

    cleanHeaderLine = cleanHeaderLine.replace(/,+$/, "");

    console.log(cleanHeaderLine);

    csv_lines[0] = cleanHeaderLine;

    var newCsvLines = [];

    csv_lines.forEach(function(line){
        if (line.charAt(0) == ',') { line = line.slice(1); }
        var currentIndex = csv_lines.indexOf(line);
        if(currentIndex === 0){
            newCsvLines.push(line);
        }
        else {
            newCsvLines.push("\n" + line);
        }
    });

    var csvFileName = './uploads/' + fileName + '_clean.csv';

    fs.writeFileSync(csvFileName, newCsvLines);

    var fileStream=fs.createReadStream(csvFileName);
//new converter instance
    var csvConverter=new Converter({constructResult:true});

    //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished
    csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function(jsonObj){
        //console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object
        makeRecords(jsonObj);

    });

    //read from file
    fileStream.pipe(csvConverter);

    function makeRecords(result){
        console.log(result.length);

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connection established to', url);

                var categoryName = metaFields.subjectCategory;

                var collectionName = categoryName.replace(/ /g,"_");

                db.open(function(err, client){
                    client.createCollection(collectionName, function(err, col) {
                    });

                    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

                    for(var i =0;i < result.length; i++){
                        //console.log(result[i]);

                        var dataRecord = result[i];

                            dataRecord.OriginalDocumentName = fileName;
                            dataRecord.DocumentAuthor = metaFields.documentAuthor;
                            dataRecord.TabName = tabName;
                            dataRecord.SubjectCategory = metaFields.subjectCategory;
                            dataRecord.Subject = metaFields.subject;
                            dataRecord.DateDocumentProduced = metaFields.dateDocumentProduced;
                            dataRecord.DateDocumentReceived = metaFields.dateDocumentReceived;
                            dataRecord.DocumentSubmitter = metaFields.documentSubmitter;
                            dataRecord.DocumentReviewer = metaFields.documentReviewer;
                            dataRecord.OriginalSource = metadataFields.originalSource,
                            dataRecord.DataVersion = metadataFields.dataVersion,
                            dataRecord.DataFields = newCsvLines[0];

                        var inserted = 0;

                        for(var i = 0;i < result.length; i++) {
                            var dataRecord = result[i];
                            collection.insert(dataRecord, function (err) {
                                if (++inserted == result.length) {
                                    console.log("finished");
                                    db.close();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

                //console.log("finished");
                //db.close();
            }
        });

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out, I have misplaced the definition of these extra fields.
I also had var dataRecord defined twice.
Once I have put the extra fields AFTER the var dataRecord, everything was being saved as it should.